# flink: Flink Shell throws NullPointerException

Tags: apache-flink

1. I am using Flink Interactive Shell to execute WordCount. It works with a file size of 10MB. But with a 100MB file the shell throws a NullPointerException:

:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.accumulators.SerializedListAccumulator.deserializeList(SerializedListAccumulator.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.collect(DataSet.scala:549)
    at .<init>(<console>:22)

at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:760)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:805)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:717)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:581)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:588)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:591)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:601)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:598)
at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:104)
at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:82)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ILoop.scala:598)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ILoop.scala:598)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ILoop.scala:598)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:130)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:597)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:597)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReader(ILoop.scala:135)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretAllFrom(ILoop.scala:596)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$loadCommand$1.apply(ILoop.scala:660)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$loadCommand$1.apply(ILoop.scala:659)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.withFile(ILoop.scala:653)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loadCommand(ILoop.scala:659)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(ILoop.scala:262)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(ILoop.scala:262)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:81)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:712)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:581)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:588)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:591)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:882)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:837)
at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.startShell(FlinkShell.scala:84)
at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.main(FlinkShell.scala:54)
at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell.main(FlinkShell.scala)
```

I work on a linux system (16MB RAM). What could be the problem there?

My code (adapted from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/quickstart/scala_api_quickstart.html) :

```
 var filename = new String(<myFileName>)
 var text = env.readTextFile(filename)
 var counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }.map { (_, 1)   }.groupBy(0).sum(1)
 var result = counts.collect()
```

2. I also noticed, that flink executes the program only on one core. After setting the parallelism with env.getConfig.setParallelism(4) and running the program again another exception occurred:

part 1:

```
    org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:413)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:356)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:349)
    at org.apache.flink.client.RemoteExecutor.executePlanWithJars(RemoteExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.client.RemoteExecutor.executePlan(RemoteExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ScalaShellRemoteEnvironment.execute(ScalaShellRemoteEnvironment.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:789)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.scala:576)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.collect(DataSet.scala:544)
    at .<init>(<console>:28)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:760)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:805)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:717)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:581)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:588)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:591)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:601)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:598)
    at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:104)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:82)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ILoop.scala:598)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ILoop.scala:598)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ILoop.scala:598)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:130)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(ILoop.scala:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReader(ILoop.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretAllFrom(ILoop.scala:596)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$loadCommand$1.apply(ILoop.scala:660)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$loadCommand$1.apply(ILoop.scala:659)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.withFile(ILoop.scala:653)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loadCommand(ILoop.scala:659)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(ILoop.scala:262)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(ILoop.scala:262)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:81)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:712)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:581)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:588)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:591)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:882)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:837)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.startShell(FlinkShell.scala:84)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.main(FlinkShell.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell.main(FlinkShell.scala)
```

part 2:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$receiveWithLogMessages$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:314)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.ActorLogMessages$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogMessages.scala:43)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.ActorLogMessages$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogMessages.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.ActorLogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogMessages.scala:29)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:92)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Not enough free slots available to run the job. You can decrease the operator parallelism or increase the number of slots per TaskManager in the configuration. Task to schedule: < Attempt #0 (CHAIN DataSource (at .<init>(<console>:26) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat)) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at .<init>(<console>:27)) -> Map (Map at .<init>(<console>:27)) -> Combine(SUM(1)) (2/4)) @ (unassigned) - [SCHEDULED] > with groupID < fc507fbb50fea681c726ca1d824c7577 > in sharing group < SlotSharingGroup [fc507fbb50fea681c726ca1d824c7577, fb90f780c9d5a4a9dbf983cb06bec946, 52b8abe5a21ed808f0473a599d89f046] >. Resources available to scheduler: Number of instances=1, total number of slots=1, available slots=0
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.Scheduler.scheduleTask(Scheduler.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.Scheduler.scheduleImmediately(Scheduler.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.scheduleForExecution(Execution.java:271)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionVertex.scheduleForExecution(ExecutionVertex.java:430)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.scheduleAll(ExecutionJobVertex.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.scheduleForExecution(ExecutionGraph.java:508)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:606)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$receiveWithLogMessages$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:190)
    ... 18 more
```

Does that mean the taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots? In my flink-conf.yaml is this key set to 4. But how can I set it in the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked two questions:

1. Why does `print()` not work for big `DataSet`s?

When you use `count()`, `collect()`, or `print()` on a `DataSet`, all data which has been partitioned on the task managers has to be transferred through the job manager to the client. It is best, to only use these methods for testing or to materialize small `DataSet`s. For large data, please use one of the sinks provided in Apache Flink, e.g. `writeAsTextFile(..)`. For each parallel task, one output file will be created then.

If you still want to transfer all data to the client, you may do so by increasing the framesize of Akka. Akka is a message-passing library that Flink uses under the hood. To do so, set `akka.framesize` in `flink-conf.yaml`. The default is 10485760 bytes (10 MB). `akka.framesize: 100mb` will increase it to 100 MB.

For Apache Flink 1.0 some committers have considered to remove this limit and there is already a pull request to use another means of transportation for large materialized DataSets.

2. What are task slots and how do they relate to the parallelism?

The default configuration of Flink starts one task slot per task manager. When you start the Scala shell in local mode, it only starts one task manager. The total number of task slots is thus one. When you change the parallelism to `N`, you need at least `N` task slots to execute this operation in parallel. So either you increase the number of task slots in the `flink-conf.yaml` or you start additional task managers. If you just run locally, I would advise to simply increase the number of task slots. For more information see the Flink documentation on http://flink.apache.org.

**edit**: If you run the Scala-Shell, an embedded Flink cluster is started with only one task manager. You can start a local cluster using `./bin/start-local.sh` and then connect to it using the Scala shell's host and port parameters (host: localhost, port: 6123).

Comment: Ok, the parallel execution worked with start-local.sh and setParallelism. Thank you for the advice.

But now I have a problem with writeAsText()-method. I thought the method would create a file with the result of my application. But that didn't work. I used 

    counts.writeAsText("file:///<filepath>/<filename>.txt")

This didn't create a file. I also tried to create a file manually first and use its file name, but it didn't work either. Am I using the method wrong?

Comment: And I have also a general question. I want to compare flinks performance to a singled-threaded implementation of the same algorithm. Thats why I used collect(). I wanted to materialize the result-DataSet because I thought, it would be appropriate for this comparison. Do you think the writeAsText()-method would also work there? What does the method do exactly?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to use env.execute() after writing to a file? The reason for the execute is that, by default, all Flink sinks are lazy and don't execute until the execution is started.

Comment: For a fair comparison, you should not use collect() because this involves an extra step and instantiates all the results in the memory of the client. Use one of the provided sinks (i.e. writeAsText or perhaps your own custom sink). Then set the parallelism to 1 for single-threaded comparison. Btw, please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes, I didn't use the env.execute(). Now it worked, thanks! And I just accepted your answer. Sorry, I am a newbie here, I forgot about the accepting.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I could help!