# Integration of non-parallelizable task with high memory demands in Flink pipeline

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink in a Yarn Cluster to process data using various sources and sinks. At some point in the topology, there is an operation that cannot be parallelized and furthermore needs access to a lot of memory. In fact, the API I am using for this step needs its input in array-form. Right now, I have implemented it something like

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataSet<Pojo> input = ...
List<Pojo> inputList = input.collect();
Pojo[] inputArray = inputList.toArray();
Pojo[] resultArray = costlyOperation(inputArray);
List<Pojo> resultList = Arrays.asList(resultArray);
DataSet<Pojo> result = env.fromCollection(resultList);
result.otherStuff()
```

1. This solution seems rather unnatural. Is there a straight-forward way to incorporate this task into my Flink pipeline?
2. I have read in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373043/flink-flink-shell-throws-nullpointerexception/33374070#33374070) that the `collect()` function should not be used for large datasets. I believe the fact that collecting the dataset into a list and then an array does not happen parallely is not my biggest problem right now, but would you still prefer to write what I called `input` above into a file and build an array from that?
3. I have also seen the [options](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html#managed-memory) to configure managed memory in flink. In principle, it might be possible to tune this in a way so that enough heap is left for the expensive operation. On the other hand, I am afraid that the performance of all the other operators in the topology might suffer. What is your opinion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the "collect->array->costlyOperation->array->fromCollection" step by a key-less reduce operation with a surrogate key that has a unique value for all tuples such that you get only a single partition. This would be Flink like.

In your costly operation itself, that is implemented as a `GroupReduceFunction`, you will get an iterator over the data. If you do not need to access all data "at once", you also safe heap space as you do not need to keep all data in-memory within reduce (but this depends of course what your costly operation computes).

As an alternative, you could also call `reduce()` **without** a previous `groupBy()`. However, you do not get an iterator or an output collector and can only compute partial aggregates. (see "Reduce" in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/programming_guide.html#transformations)

Using Flink style operations has the advantage, that the data is kept in the cluster. If you do `collect()` the result is transfered to the client, the costly operation is executed in the client, and the result is transfered back to the cluster. Furthermore, if the input is large, Flink will automatically spill the intermediate result to disc for you.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Unfortunately, the costly operation does need all data at once. So the way to go would be to (1) group all elements of the dataset into one set and then (2) aggregate the array in the GroupReduceFunction, right? Is there a natural way to do (1) without introducing an unnecessary surrogate key? Furthermore, would you reommend to define for (2) a (Rich)GroupReduceFunction<Pojo, Pojo[]>, where the output dataset really just consists of the one huge array or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just updated my answer. I guess you need to stick with surrogate key, as you need the iterator and output collector... About the output: I would not output `Pojo[]` but call `Collector.collect()` for each element in your output array within your function. Maybe you do not need to assembly the output array in memory and just output tuples directly instead of adding them to the result. Otherwise, just loop over the array in your function.